# Django serializeArray() from 2 django.form fields inside one form tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, forms

I have 2 `django.forms.ModelForms`(detalle and camion) and I need to render them inside ONE `<form>` tag, and then take the information with JavaScript to put the data into a table inside the same template. So I have something like this in my template.

```
<form id="agregar-servicio-form">

  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
         {{ detalle_form.tipo | as_crispy_field }}
     </div>
     ...
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
          {{ camion_form.modelo | as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
          {{ camion_form.capacidad | as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
         ...
  </div>

  </form>
```

I can take all the form data with javascript/jquery with the `serializeArray()` method BUT when i do this with this form (`$('#agregar-servicio-form').serializeArray();`) the data captured is only from the `detalle_form` form.

```
{'tipo':'123'} //in this example
```

**How can I get all the data from the different form-fields inside the form tag? even when there are 2 or more `django ModelForms`?**

Comment: I'd avise using this guy https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object

Comment: to use this I need to change my fields' names, so it will be a headache with django, I don´t think this is a good option, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

from http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form_helper.html

> form_tag = True
>
> It specifies if  tags should be rendered
>   when using a Layout. If set to False it renders the form without the
>    tags. Defaults to True.

Also read about

> disable_csrf = False

so you can declare base helper class:

```
class CommonFormHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CommonFormHelper, self).__init__()
        self.disable_csrf = True
        self.form_tag = False
```

then update your modelforms

```
class ModelFormOne(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = CommonFormHelper()

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'someField1', 'someField2',
        )

        super(ModelFormOne, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelOne
```

let's look at template:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mainForm">{% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form_one form_one.helper %}
    {% crispy form_two form_two.helper %}

    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-submit center-block" type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

finally in your view implement some kind of Mixin class, which you can add as superclass to your Create and Update views (It's **NOT** a final one, that you can simply copypaste, only thoughts from my head, you should **accomplish it**)

```
class ObjectsAddEditMixin(object):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def get_pks(self, **kwargs):
        self.pk1 = kwargs.get('pk1')
        self.pk2 = kwargs.get('pk2')

    def get_objects():
       self.objects = {}
       self.objects['form_one'] = get_object_ot_404(ModelOne, pk=self.pk1)
       self.objects['form_two'] = get_object_ot_404(ModelTwo, pk=self.pk2)

       return self.objects

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk_1 and self.pk_2:
            self.objects = self.get_objects()
            form_one = self.form_class_one(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=self.objects['form_one'])
            form_two = self.form_class_two(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=self.objects['form_two'])
        else:
            form_one = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
            form_two = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form_one.is_valid() and form_two.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form_one, form_two)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form_one, form_two)

    def form_valid(self, form_one, form_two):
        form_one.save()
        form_two.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form_one, form_two):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(
                form_one=form_one,
                form_two=form_two
            )
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('app:url_name')


class ObjectsCreateView(ObjectsAddEditMixin, View):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ObjectsCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form_one'] = self.form_class_one(instance=ModelOne())
        context['form_two'] = self.form_class_two(instance=ModelTwo())

        return context


class ObjectsUpdateView(ObjectsAddEditMixin, View):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ObjectsUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form_one'] = self.form_class_two(instance=self.objects['form_one'])
        context['form_two'] = self.form_class_one(instance=self.objects['form_two'])

        return context
```